# Checkbox not hittable on iPad - XCUITest Apple

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, fastlane, xcuitest

I'm working on a XCUITest for Fastlane Screenshot automation. All of the below code works totally fine on every iPhone Simulator. It's just a problem with the iPad.

After starting the app I handle the permissions and than there opens a TermsOfUse Dialog:

[image]

Everytime I reach the step for checking the checkbox (after that an Accept button apears) the UITest crashes with the following error:

`Not hittable: Switch, 0x600000397010, traits: 9007345283760129, label: 'termsOfUseAcceptedCheckbox', value: 0`

This is the Code of the handler:

```
func handleTermsOfUse() {
        RunLoop.current.run(mode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode, before: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10) as Date)

    let termsOfUseAcceptedCheckbox = app.switches["termsOfUseAcceptedCheckbox"]
    self.waitForElementToAppear(element: termsOfUseAcceptedCheckbox, timeout: 40)
    if(termsOfUseAcceptedCheckbox.exists) {
        termsOfUseAcceptedCheckbox.isAccessibilityElement = true
        termsOfUseAcceptedCheckbox.tap()
    }


    let termsOfUseAcceptedButton = app.buttons["termsOfUseAcceptedButton"]
    self.waitForElementToAppear(element: termsOfUseAcceptedButton, timeout: 40)
    if(termsOfUseAcceptedButton.exists) {
        termsOfUseAcceptedButton.isAccessibilityElement = true
        termsOfUseAcceptedButton.tap()
    }
}
```

And this is the part calling the method:

```
 override func testApp() {
        super.testApp()

        snapshot("01splashScreen")
        //self.handlePermission()
        self.handleTermsOfUse()
        sleep(5)
        snapshot("02index")
}
```

I don't know why this happens just on **iPad** and works fine on iPhone.
I tried it with a `forceTap()` method but it was no success.

```
func forceTapElement() {
        if self.isHittable {
            self.tap()
        }
        else {
            let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0))
            coordinate.tap()
        }
```

I hope someone knows what to do to get it to work on iPad Simulators as well.

Comment: have you check with View Debugger , it is looking out of View

Comment: @Dhiru yeah, but no it's perfectly inside my ToU Container. And it is no problem for the test finding the checkbox just the 'hitting' is the problem

Comment: is it "enabled" ?

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrov yes it is enabled

Comment: @breezertwo replace the existing coordinate with this line in forceTapElement method: let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5))

Comment: @Confused I tried this to, but unfortunately no success